# Finding datasheets for 30+ year old ICs?

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, datasheet, intel

Anyone who can lead me in the right direction for finding datasheet for some old ICs?

I've googled every possible variation of the numbers, which are:
MSM93H002-74 (DIP64, marked OKI/Intel), C1185 (DIP16, marked OKI) and
2904DX (DIP8, marked JRC)

Edit: These are all mounted on the main board of the air condition controller in an old car I'm trying to reverse engineer since some of the caps have spewed their electrolyte and etched away some of the traces.
It doesn't seem to be any clock/xtal sources on the board, so I'm doubting the DIP64 could be a microcontroller?

Thanks

Comment: I think that You are unable to find the datasheets not becauose of the age of the IC's, but the fact, that manufacturer don't want You to see them.

Comment: @fifi_22 I agree.

Comment: You can try to write directly to the manufacturer, I have gotten lucky with the technical support service sometimes.

Comment: 2904 is probably a dual op-amp similar to LM2904. MSMxxx sounds like a standard OKI part number. Maybe a mask programmed micro or memory. C1185 DRAM maybe?

Comment: I've got the easy one, I think: JRC NJM2904 is an opamp, likely close to the well-known LM2904. Datasheet is here: https://www.njr.com/electronic_device/PDF/NJM2904_E.pdf. There is still a doubt, because the datasheet doesn't explain the marking and so there is no clar explanation for the "DX" letters you see on the chip. The "D" may be the package: datasheet mentions NJM2904D as DIP-8, which is consistent. The "X" may be a date code, or something like that. OKI stuff seems much more difficult to get.

Comment: JRC is well known for making opamp clones so Spehro probably nailed that one...

Comment: Going out on a limb here, but a dual OKI/Intel marked 64-pin DIP device makes me think it's an Intel MCS-96 series microcontroller licensed to OKI (and probably with some internal OKI part number).

Comment: Thanks for the inputs! Dual op amp IC seems to be correct looking at what its connected to on the PCB. Updated the question with some more (useful?) info.

Comment: @brhans OKI also made MCS-51 and MCS-48 parts (but better, because they were in CMOS).